# Pythong gui with checkboxes

Tags: python, user-interface, checkbox, submit, wget

Is it possible to create a gui in Python that has checkboxes for software I'd like to download and that has a submit button to download all checked ones rather than automatically downloading them everytime one of them is checked?
Found alot of tutorials that use wget to accomplish the download when a box is checked, but none to what I need : checkboxes with a "submit" button.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are plenty of python GUI options... tkinter, pyqt, wxpython, kivy, etc.

please refer to the [GuiProgramming](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) python wiki article

Comment: I'm sure there are many, but I'm yet to find an example for what I need. most of the tutorials are for tkinter, but all of them are with checkboxes with imediate acction.

Comment: @apoklyps3 You just map the button being clicked to a function. That function checks if the checkbox is ticked. The checkbox only will perform an action if the checkbox being clicked is mapped to a function.